# Opencart - How to remove "en-gb" from url

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I've installed 4.0.1.1 version from OC website.
I'm setting the shop to be available in only one country - UK and only one language English.

I wanted to remove `en-gb` from the URL.

For example:

```
example.com/en-gb/catalog/books
```

should be

```
example.com/catalog/books
```

I've done some searching and as suggested I've removed all zones and countries except UK but this doesn't solve the issue.

How do I get rid of `en-gb` from all URLs? Can it be done from `.htaccess`? If yes how?

Comment: "Can it be done from .htaccess" - No. You can issue a "redirect" in `.htaccess` to remove "en-gb/" from the URL if you are changing an existing URL structure and the old URLs (that contain "en-gb/") have been indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties, but you still need to actually change the URLs in your application.

Comment: I think it will mess up with the rest of OC as per someones reply on their git hub https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/12145#issuecomment-1399079015

Comment: There are discussions going on for the url pov. They can use SEO keyword to look for product or entity to resolve to right url. But it might take time.

Answer (score 1):

Open file /system/library/url.php

Find the following code

```
if (!$js) {
  return str_replace('&', '&amp;', $url);
} else {
  return $url;
}
```

Replace with the following code:

```
if (!$js) {
  return str_replace('en-gb/', '', str_replace('&', '&amp;', $url));
} else {
  return str_replace('en-gb/', '',$url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change core code then run following query to your mysql directly. I tried following solution in Opencart 4.x version

```
INSERT INTO `oc_seo_url` (`store_id`, `language_id`, `key`, `value`, `keyword`, `sort_order`)
VALUES ('0', '1', 'language', 'en-gb', '', '0');
```